# applying shadow and z-index to an absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to achieve a bump in a navigation bar, the navigation bar is supposed to have a box-shadow...however the bump needs it as well on the bottom... somehow i cant put the bump behind the navigation bar, is that a known issue or am i missing something? thanks a lot.

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

.c-header {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.c-site-nav {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.c-site-nav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.c-site-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  width: 40%;
}
.c-site-nav__item a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.c-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.c-logo::after {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<header class="c-header">
  <div class="c-logo">
  </div>
  <nav class="c-site-nav">
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ueber_uns">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="tel:+49234234234">34234234</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion, i just realized the easiest way to achieve it, would be to place another pseudo element on top of the pseudo that creates the bump to get rid of (or cover up) the shadow of the bump

```css
body {
  background: beige;
  margin: 0;
}

.c-header {
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  background: white;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.c-site-nav {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.c-site-nav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.c-site-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  width: 40%;
}
.c-site-nav__item a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.c-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.c-logo::after {
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  content: '';
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.c-logo::before {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="c-header">
  <div class="c-logo">
</div>
  <nav class="c-site-nav">
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
      <li><a href="/">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
      <li><a href="/">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the expected result, but I managed to get this done by putting the

```
  <div class="c-logo">
```

outside of the header element.

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

.c-header {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.c-site-nav {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.c-site-nav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.c-site-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  width: 40%;
}
.c-site-nav__item a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.c-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.c-logo::after {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<header class="c-header">
  </div>
  <nav class="c-site-nav">
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ueber_uns">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="tel:+49234234234">34234234</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
  <div class="c-logo">
```

Comment: Or remove z-index:9999; from the header css

Comment: thanks @kevin i just realized that the whole idea can't be achieved like that since obviously the shadow from the bar is now on the bump as well

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned `box-shadow` on pseudo selector `:after` for center `circle`, you could reduce the `blur-radius` on that particular element as below,

> box-shadow : offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

.c-header {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.c-site-nav {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.c-site-nav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.c-site-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  width: 40%;
}
.c-site-nav__item a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.c-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.c-logo::after {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<header class="c-header">
  <div class="c-logo">
  </div>
  <nav class="c-site-nav">
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ueber_uns">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="c-site-nav__item">
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">asd</a></li>
        <li><a href="tel:+49234234234">34234234</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks @frnt , thats a nice idea but it will always drop a bit of shadow on the top header

Comment: @HendrikEng If you plan to add to much then yes, or you could keep on minus the blur till you don't get planned effect. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/8wydo9z7/

Comment: thanks again, its a good way but i figured to have it pixel perfect the easiest way would be to place another pseudo element on top of the bump to cover the first elements shade.

Comment: Welcome @HendrikEng That's a nice approach to hide extended effects.

Answer (score 0):

Change  the Style of  'C-logo' . only change the Z-index from 1 to -1 hope this will help you

```css
`.c-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: -1;
}`
```